# How to access the secure cookie in express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I have set cookie in one api.

```js
res.cookie('login', result.id, {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
});
res.cookie('user', token, {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true
});
```

But when I  access it from other api, I can only access login cookie but not the user cookie

```js
console.log(req.cookies);
console.log(req.headers['cookie']);
```

Comment: What does "access from other api" mean?  Please explain in enough detail that someone could reproduce your setup to fully understand.  `secure` cookies are NOT sent with http requests, only with https requests.  So, if your other api is http, the browser won't send that cookie.  That's what the `secure` aspect of the cookie means.  It's only sent over a secure transport.

Comment: For more info on the `secure` attribute for cookies, see [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies).